# Trying to figure out why balloon pop game is not resetting clickCount

Tags: javascript, function

I have followed along with video from video number 76 of the Udemy "last Intro to Programming Course". I have moved code that was included all in one function to another function called "draw" I  have reviewed the video multiple times and I cannot see any difference between my code and the video. The goal of the code is to reset the clickCount back to zero. Here is the code. Help would be greatly appreciated everything is working except resetting of the balloon size and clickCount with each timeout:

```js
let startButton = document.getElementById('start-button')
let inflateButton = document.getElementById('inflate-button')

let clickCount = 0
let height = 120
let width = 100
let inflationRate = 20
let maxsize = 300
let popCount = 0

function startGame() {

  startButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
  inflateButton.removeAttribute("disabled")

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("it's been 3 seconds")

    inflateButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
    startButton.removeAttribute("disabled")

    clickCount = 0
    height = 120
    width = 100
    draw()

  }, 3000)
}

function inflate() {
  clickCount++

  height += inflationRate
  width += inflationRate

  if (height >= maxsize) {
    console.log("pop the balloon")
    popCount++
    height = 0
    width = 0
  }
  draw()
}

function draw() {
  let balloonElement = document.getElementById("balloon")
  let clickCountElem = document.getElementById("click-count")
  let popCountElem = document.getElementById('pop-count')

  balloonElement.style.height = height + "px"
  balloonElement.style.width = width + "px"

  clickCountElem.innerText = clickCount.toString()
  popCountElem.innerText = popCount.toString()
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Balloon Pop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>

  <button id="start-button" onclick="startGame()" >START GAME</button>

</div>

 <button id="inflate-button" onclick="inflate()" disabled="true">Inflate <span id="click-count"> </span></button> 

 <div>
 <span>Balloons Popped</span>
 <span id="pop-count"></span>
 </div>
 <div id="balloon" class="balloon" ></div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and create a functioning snippet using the editor.

Comment: Please don't assume we're familiar with the course you're referring to. You need to explain what this is supposed to do, and what it's doing wrong. You say you modified it from some other program, but we don't know how that program worked.

Comment: You're never calling `inflate` function in your code. Also, it's not clear what you actually want to reset, the title says `popCount`, in the text you're talking about `clickCount`.

Comment: You instantiate the popCount as a global variable, but then the only thing you ever do to it is increment it. There is nowhere in your code where you re-assign the value back to 0. When should that happen (as in, when which function executes)? All you'd need to do is add the line `popCount = 0` in the function where you want it to reset

Comment: This is a game that pumps a balloon when the user clicks a button. The user has 3 seconds to click the button until the balloon reaches a certain size and pops. Right now it is functioning, however I am trying to zero out the number of clicks and reset the height/width with each timeout.

Comment: According to the video it looks like adding these lines should have the effect of zeroing out clickCount and resetting the size:    clickCount = 0
    height = 120
    width = 100
    draw()

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by looking at the source tab in dev tools. For whatever reason all of the lines weren't being saved or loaded to Chrome from VSCode. What I did was copy all the code from VSCode and pasted it into Notepad, saved and then refreshed. All is working fine now.